# How to prepare for Magento Developer Certification exam in 2 days?

Tags: certification

I have been developing for Magento for the last 6 months at my job, and I've created quite a few modules and fixed quite a few bugs. My employee booked an exam on Monday, they have the client coming on Tuesday and to impress them more, they want me to pass the exam. How should I prepare for it fast? Please don't close it, I really need help.

Answer (score 7):

There is no fast way to do it.  Unless you can answer most of the questions outlined in the study guide then you're not ready. I've been working with Magento since the beginning, went to the MagentoU taught by Ben Marks and Vinai Kopp in California, studied that guide like crazy and took the test and failed it the first time (missed by just a few points).  I waited and studied for few more months and passed it the 2nd try in 2012.

I don't know if they still do it but they used to give a discount to try again if you fail the first time but I think I had to wait 90 days to retake it (anyone correct me if I'm wrong about those two things or if it's changed).

The best advice I can give is to make sure you understand everything in the study guide. The side-effect from studying for this test is getting a deeper understanding of Magento.  Taking a test like this with the goal of just passing the test is the wrong reason.

Comment: If only he had that third day..

Answer (score 1):

This is really dangerous. You are telling the entire Magento SE community your company wants to impress a client with you passing an exam for a framework you don't know anything about. If you accept this you will be probably asked to do something twice as crazy next time and the next developer joining your company will have this as a negative background. 
Please keep in mind everyone here is living out of coding Magento. If you do this it might be negative for the entire community and other companies/agencies might take this as normal behaviour. And it is not. The exam is not the most complex thing in the world but it should not be taken lightly just to sell some more stores.

TL;DR please make your company respect you. I can understand you want to keep your job, but instead of doing the exam you should post your company name here.

Comment: 'you should post your company name here'.  No, you should not.

Comment: Sure, let them keep harassing you.

Comment: "framework you don't know anything about" - I've been developing on it for 6 months

Comment: And I have been developing Magento for 6 years and still have some things to learn. And by some I mean a lot. I can understand you think this is a bad idea, but please try to make them respect you in any way you can. Imagine you enter a new company where the last developer worked for 12 hs straight and now you have to do the same. This is exactly the same case here.

Comment: I agree with you that this is an unrealistic expectation that this company is holding for @iwanttolearn however, outing that company on a public forum isn't the way to handle this.  May I suggest the workplace stackexchange for issues such as these.